# The program stops when it has a space input. Even when using the cin.getline

Tags: c++

so the program tells me to scan for a whitespace input. The program stops whenever the website inputs a whitespace and then immediately says that the input is not a whitespace.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

bool isWhiteSpace(char letter[0]);

int main() 
{
  char character[0];
  cout << "Enter a character: ";
  cin.getline(character,sizeof(character); 
  if(isWhiteSpace(character))
    cout << "The character you entered is a whitespace character" << endl;
  else
    cout << "The character you entered is not a whitespace character" << endl;
}

bool isWhiteSpace(char letter[0])
{
  return(isspace(letter[0])||letter[0]=='\0'||letter[0]==' ');
}
```

(The code has been edited but it still doesnt work)

Comment: `cin>>character;` will **never** input a whitespace character.

Comment: Side note: you can do very little with an array of 0 size in C++. Check the compiler diagnostics to see if it emits any warnings over  `char character[0];`.